# facing error while installing facerecognition and dlib

Tags: python, cmake, pip, face-recognition, dlib

I tried installing dlib files I'm getting this error:

```
cd C:\Users\Dnyaneshwar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
PS C:\Users\Dnyaneshwar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages> python setup.py install

  You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
  are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
  that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
  development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.

  subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Users\Dnyaneshwar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Dnyaneshwar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Dnyaneshwar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Dnyaneshwar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Dnyaneshwar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I have installed the C++ CMake tool for windows but I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

i had to downgrade my python from 3.11 to 3.9
now it worked